# Regular expression selectively match

Tags: regex

Suppose there are the following strings:

```
https://domain1.com
https://domain2.com    
https://domain3.com
https://testdomain.com
https://domain4.com
https://domain5.com
random text
293928382
```

How can I match only strings that have `http` but also exclude ones that contain `testdomain` for example? Currently I have this which excludes `testdomain`

```
^((?!testdomain).)*$
```

However I don't know how to combine the `http` matching part with the above expression. Can someone please help me combine the above with matching `http` as well?

The objective is to match:

```
https://domain1.com
https://domain2.com    
https://domain3.com
https://domain4.com
https://domain5.com
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use: `^https?://(?!.*/(?:www\.)?testdomain\.).+$`

Comment: I tried this expression here: https://regex101.com but it doesn't match any of the strings in my question though.

Comment: Correction; it would be `^https?://(?!(?:www\.)?testdomain\.).+$` See demo: https://regex101.com/r/y2Ra3D/1

Comment: Great, that now works! Can you please set this as the answer? :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with a negative lookaheadd:

```
^https?://(?!(?:www\.)?testdomain\.).+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/y2Ra3D/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^https?://`: Match `http://` or `https://` at the start
- `(?!(?:www\.)?testdomain\.)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have `www.testdomain.com` or `testdomain.com` right after
- `.+$`: Match 1+ of any character